# How can I vote for "Leave open" outside of the review queue?

Tags: support, review

Sometimes I stumble upon a question where some close votes already have been cast (but the question is not closed yet). How I can vote for "Leave Open" now ? I can not search for a specific question in the review queue, can I ? The "close-dialog" on the question page does not contain the "Leave Open" option, as far as I can see.

Comment: There does seem to be an asymmetry in the process and I assume it's by design. Thus if I review something and click "Leave open" that doesn't change anything that I can see except that is recorded in a history. As I understand it, 4 votes to close are not reduced to 3  because I choose Leave open. You're blowing against a wind.

Comment: @NickCox Thank you, I did not know that. Will drop a comment next time instead.

Comment: But how does one prevent closing it as soon as it is in the queue ? If the only options are "add another close vote" or "do nothing" which is equivalent to "Leave open" ?

Comment: You can't prevent it; you can only refrain from voting to close. The wider context as I understand it: the machinery is intended to promote the removal of poor questions, with scope for the OP to improve the question and for people to vote to re-open and for close decisions to be discussed. Setting aside what moderators can do unilaterally, the CV rule is that 5 people have to vote to close for that to be effective. The most negative view of this, which has been expressed, is that that gives a lot of freedom for any 5 misguided and malevolent people with enough reputation to be destructive.

Comment: Functionalities like this one are common to all SE sites, so it's best to look at [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com) as to whether this has been asked before. Searching for "vote to leave open" or similar turns up ["Allow voting “Vote to not close” from the question without being in a review"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151476/256777).

Comment: Not a solution, but a way to deal with it: you can also comment on the question and explain why you believe it should remain open.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that from the Q&A page, just like you can't vote 'leave closed' when there are pending reopen votes.

You *can* search in the Close Votes review queue with a bit of a workaround; you can filter by type of close vote (not suitable for this site, needs details or clarity, etc.) or by tag. Choose the least used tag (that's the rightmost one) and you'll have a good chance to find it immediately.

[image]
<sub>(screenshot from Math.SE since I don't have enough reputation here)</sub>